# Are reference angles also coterminal angles?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

It would seem reference angles end up on the same terminal ray, so wouldn't it be safe to assume that reference angles are also coterminal angles by classification?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

No. The reference angle has the same terminal ray as the original angle, but they may have different starting rays.

[image]

In the diagram, $\alpha=\angle AOB$ is the original angle, and $\beta=\angle COB$ is the reference angle. They both have the terminal ray $\overrightarrow{OB}$ but different starting rays. (Note that we consider $\beta$ to be positive, despite its clockwise direction.)

A reference angle is one between $0$ and $90$ degrees that has the same sine, cosine, and tangent in absolute value. It has little to do with coterminal angles.